# MongoDB : How can I reformat this code to include a sort on the name field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api-design

How can I reformat this block in order to add sorting on the Name field?

```
   Router.route('/hospitals/search/:searchString')
      .get(function (req, res) {
        const searchString = decodeURIComponent(req.params.searchString)
        HospitalModel.find({
          $or: [
            {Name: {$regex: searchString, $options: 'i'}},
            {City: {$regex: searchString, $options: 'i'}}
          ]
        }, function (err, data) {
          const response = (err)
            ? {error: true, message: 'Server Error when querying hospitals collection.'}
            : {error: false, message: data}
          res.json(response)
        })
      })
```

I'm new to both mongo and API creation in general. The examples I've found don't really fit the way I've written this and I'm sort of lost at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. Sorting can be done in different ways in mongoose.

Following are the examples for that

```
HospitalModel.find({}).sort('Name').exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
HospitalModel.find({}).sort({Name: 1}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
HospitalModel.find({}, null, {sort: {Name: 1}}, function(err, docs) { ... });
HospitalModel.find({}, null, {sort: [['Name', -1]]}, function(err, docs) { ... });
```

Generally what i follow is in this way. It will work for you too.

```
 Router.route('/hospitals/search/:searchString')
     .get(function(req, res) {
         const searchString = decodeURIComponent(req.params.searchString)
         HospitalModel.find({
             $or: [
                 { Name: { $regex: searchString, $options: 'i' } },
                 { City: { $regex: searchString, $options: 'i' } }
             ]
         }, null, { sort: { Name: 1 } }, function(err, data) {
             const response = (err) ? { error: true, message: 'Server Error when querying hospitals collection.' } : { error: false, message: data }
             res.json(response)
         })
     })
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm. I appreciate the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
       HospitalModel.find(
     $or: [{
       Name: {
         $regex: searchString,`
         $options: 'i'
       }
     }, {
       City: {
         $regex: searchString,
         $options: 'i'
       }
     }]
   ) .sort({
       Name: 1
     }).exec(function(err, data) {
       const response = (err) ? {
         error: true,
         message: 'Server Error when querying hospitals collection.'
       } : {
         error: false,
         message: data
       }

       return res.json(response);
     });
```